# Service Discovery in Cloud Run

Tags: node.js, grpc, google-cloud-run

I have two micro services on Google Cloud Run which are meant to communicate via gRPC

1. Products Service
2. Customer Service.

Product Service is started like below:

```
....
let server = new grpc.Server();
server.addService(products_proto.Product.service, {...});
server.bindAsync("0.0.0.0:50051", grpc.ServerCredentials.createInsecure(), () => {
    server.start();
    console.log('Product Service Started');
});
...
```

How can Product Service locate Customer Service in production without explicitly specifying the port?

Or do I have to always ask my colleagues to tell me the port they exposed their micro-service on?

Wouldn't that be a very tedious process?

I want my product service to connect to my customer service using something like

```
 ....
        new customer_proto.Customer("customer-service", grpc.credentials.createInsecure());
  ....
```

Instead of

```
 ....
        new customer_proto.Customer("0.0.0.0:50052", grpc.credentials.createInsecure());
  ....
```

Can this be achieved?

Comment: Services deployed to Cloud Run are exposed on hostnames combining the service name with some (random) hashed value and an obfuscated reference to the region (e.g. `{something}-{hash}-{hash}` on a subdomain `a.run.app` and **only** expose port 433 (e.g. `{something}-{hash}-{hash}.a.run.app:443` so, you only need  a fully-qualified domain name. Such domain names are generally `CNAME`'d to custom domains (e.g. `our-service.example.com`). There are many service discovery solutions and these often resolve to domain names..

Comment: @DazWilkin Thank you for your response. However, my use case is that each service is meant to be accessed via a path which I have already configured via firebase hosting  such that a service should be invoked in the form ```api.myapp.com/users``` will this still work?

Comment: Because I attempted that and I am getting the following error:

```Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Failed to parse DNS address dns:https://api.myapp.com/users```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with Firebase Hosting. You **can't** map gRPC services onto URL paths.

Comment: Infact here is the full client connection code:

        ```new customer_proto.Customer("dns:customer-service-aba10izrlb-ue.a.run.app:50051", grpc.credentials.createInsecure());```

And the error I keep getting is:

```Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: No connection established```

Comment: You can define any port you want inside Cloud Run, however, the public (external) port is always HTTPS (443).

Comment: @user15155716, did any of the comments above address your concern? If so, please post it as an answer so that other community members with similar questions will find this helpful.